# Cross Origin Issue in Iframe which is pointing to Cloudflare. Cross domain

Tags: jquery, iframe, cross-domain, cloudflare, cross-origin-read-blocking

Our main website and subdomain is pointing to cloudflare.

We are loading one chat widget in our main website using iframe. For example our Main website is **"www.example.com"** and our chat widget website is **"chat.example.com"**

Loading subdomain chat widget using iframe in our main website.

When clicking a div element in our subdomain we are adding one class for parent iframe, to increase height of the iframe using below jquery in onclick event.
`var parent = window.parent.findParent.call(window);`

So when we are doing this we are getting an error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://chat.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: You could use postMessage API to communicate between the frame and parent windows

Comment: We already with same way but cross origin error response is coming in the iframe content. tried like below in our main page.

`<iframe src='url' class='chat' id='iframe' height="530"></iframe>
iframe.onload = function() {
alert("Iframe load");
}`